# PHP file not getting variable sent via AJAX using POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a `jquery` variable to a `php` script as part of a search feature I'm building for a website. I wish to use `AJAX` to perform the request for the `php` file and so far I've gotten this as my `new-search.js` script:

```
$('#bt_search').click(function(){
        $keyword = $('#keyword').val();//get the keyword from the input box
        $contentArray = []; //Hold checked "content" filters
        $typeArray = []; //Hold checked "type" filters
        $locationArray = []; //Hold checked "location" filters

        //Content Filter - cycle through each filter and add value of checked ones to array
        $('.content-filter :checked').each(function(){
            $contentArray.push(this.value);
        })

        //Type Filter
        $('.type-filter :checked').each(function(){
            $typeArray.push(this.value);
        })

        //Location Filter
        $('.location-filter :checked').each(function(){
            $locationArray.push(this.value);
        })

        //Testing 
        console.log("Keyword: " + $keyword);
        console.log("Content Filters: " + $contentArray);
        console.log("Type Filters: " + $typeArray);
        console.log("Location Filters: " + $locationArray);


        /*
         * Make AJAX Request to "new-search-get-results.php", passing 
         * keyword and filter arrays to the requested file.
         * 
         */ 
        $.ajax({
            url: "../pages/ajax/new-search-get-results.php",
            data: JSON.stringify({keyword: $keyword}),
            type: "POST",
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
```

The above is working, however I'm running into trouble with the response I get back from the `new-search-get-results.php` file. This is the error:

```
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: keyword in C:\wamp\www\mysite.tld\pages\ajax\new-search-get-results.php on line 6
```

The line it relates to in the `php` file is: `$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];`

Does anyone know where I am going wrong so I can fix this error? This is my `new-search-get-results.php` file:

```
$keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
echo $keyword;
```

Comment: You dont need to stryingify. You must not stringify. Try `var_dump($_POST);` and see whats in there

Comment: you need to `json_decode()` your post-variable in order you send a json-string to your php-file

Comment: Yes, I just discovered that there...I don't know why I was doing that

Comment: @empiric no, he doesn't and it's `json_decode()`. besides this, it still would not work since the $_POST['keyword'] variable would still not be set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
data: JSON.stringify({keyword: $keyword}),
```

to

```
data: {keyword: $keyword},
```

Comment: glad to know it's helpful for you. you can accept helpful answer